# "Give someone a call" vs. "give someone a call back" in context

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Would you please tell if I need to use *give you a call* or *give you a call back* in the context below.

> Customer: I'm calling to schedule an appointment with the doctor at 1pm tomorrow.
>
> Receptionist: Sure. It looks like he has an opening at that time tomorrow. I'll fit you in and if anything changes, I'll give you a call (**back**).

It seems to me either one can be used. Please tell me if I'm wrong and if so, explain the logic behind using one and not the other.

Comment: I think both work here. I would've said "I'll call you back" tho. "Give you a call back" sounds awkward.

Answer (score 1):

Call simply means 'communicate or telephone someone by telephone'.
Call back means 'telephone or communicate someone as a reply by telephone'To the person–who have previously called you or communicated to you)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm afraid it doesn't answer my question. I'm aware of the difference between "call" and "call back." But, in the context the difference isn't clear.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope If you're calling someone after they called you, then you can say "call back". What about the context isn't clear? The customer called reception first. We know this because the customer says, "*I'm calling...*" What part of the context gives you doubts?